# How do you drop a corrupted INNODB database in MariaDB?

Tags: innodb, mariadb

If you try to access a table in a database of type INNODB and MariaDB tells you it isn't here, you have a corrupted database.

(I am posting this question because all of the existing questions have been "closed" by various moderators and NONE of them have a real answer.  They discuss the complexities of INNODB, and ultimately that you have to rebuild the entire database server through a torturous process.)

Answer (score 6):

This may not work for everyone, but it did work for us on several occasions:

1. Stop the database (service mysql stop)
2. edit mysql.cnf so that under [mysqld] section it has the:

   ```
   [mysqld] 
   innodb_force_recovery = 1
   ```
3. Start the database (service mysql start) and in the logfile
   you will see it force loading the bad database/table
4. log into the
   database server as root:  mysql -u root
5. run the command "show databases[ENTER]" to get a list of database
6. run he command "drop [dbname][ENTER]" where [thedb] is the database you need to drop. It will drop it but will complain that it cannot delete the directory ./[thedb].
7. Open a separate shell and go into /var/lib/mysql/[thedb]/ and remove the file(s) there.
8. Stop the database (service mysql stop)
9. Turn off the REPAIR mode by commenting out the line in
   mysql.cnf

   ```
   [mysqld]
   #innodb_force_recovery = 1
   ```
10. restart the database with the command:

    ```
    service mysql start[ENTER]
    ```

Voila.

Now recreate the database and restore from your backup.

Thanks,
David

Comment: I'm a bit confused by step 7. Did you mean to say something about deleting a file or directory?

Comment: I just re-re-read your comment.  I am sorry for the confusion.  I have cleaned up the text so it reads better.

Comment: That looks better, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: In case this is useful to anyone: I skipped steps 1 to 3 and the solution still worked.

Comment: For me, steps 1 to 3 were sufficient to drop the table properly. Thank you so much.